# How to access the authorization header in global services in Next.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, vercel

I use Nextjs as my backend framework. In the middleware I have implemented authentication and verify the token before forwarding the request to the API route. In the API route I call services in which the business logic is implemented.

In these services I want to access the email address of the user who sent the request. The email address is in the verified token and can be read via the header.

However, I do not want to read the header in each route and forward the email address to the service.

How can i make the email address globally available?

1. This does not work in the middleware, because the middleware runs on the edge.
2. In the global services I have no access to the headers.
3. I haven't read anything about anything like interceptors.

*pages/api/blogs/index.ts*

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const manageBlog = container.resolve(ManageBlog);
    switch (req.method) {
        case 'GET':
            const loadedBlog = manageBlog.readBlog();
            res.status(200).json(loadedBlog);
            break;
        default:
            res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET']);
            res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
    }
}
```

*src/module/blog/manage-blog.ts*

```
@autoInjectable()
export class ManageBlog {
    public async readBlog() {
        // GET EMAIL ADDRESS VIA TOKEN IN THE AUTHORIZATION HEADER
    }
}
```

Comment: you could write the email to token?

Comment: Sure you can write everything in the token, but email address is very common and can be enabled with the scope.